# Is it possible to migrate data from one HBASE DB to another in a different HDFS cluster?

Tags: hdfs, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have an HBASE database (with N-tables) in two cluster (West and East). Both with the same DB schema. West and East are in different domains.

How do I migrate data, from each table, with a specific group (such as employees in "HR") from West to East?

Possible(?) solutions are:

1. For each table in West, create snapshot of West then restore snapshot in East, and then delete all unwanted rows. (I would lose all data that was in
   East)
2. For each table in West, create snapshot, and somehow merge snapshot with East. Then delete all unwanted rows. (Is merging snapshot to existing HBASE possible?)
3. For each table in West, create snapshot, then clone that snapshot in East as table_to_merge. Clean up table 2 by deleting unwanted rows, then merge table_snapshot to table_target.
4. For each row in each table in West, write the same row to East. (Ideal, but I would need to create a script to connect to both HDFS Cluster which not easy because they're on two different domain)

Comment: Have you considered solution #5 - HBase replication ? It may/may not be possible depending on your Kerberos setup, see https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/fault-tolerance/content/hbase_cluster_replication_for_geographic_data_distribution.html.

Comment: HBase replication would create two synced HBase which would not achieve my goal unfortunately. The goal would be two non-synced HBase, but moving (or copying) data from one to another based on a whitelisted row key.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, this wasn't clear from your question. And true, by default HBase replication operates at column-family granularity. With HBase 2.0, there is a pluggable ReplicationEndpoint (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10504) that allows to apply custom filtering, but honestly I have not tried using it myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution after all...

1. Snapshot source HBase DB
2. Transfer source snapshot to HDFS destination
3. Clone source snapshot @ HDFS destination
4. Delete unwanted rows from cloned table (using Java HBase API)
5. Copy/merge the cloned table over to the target table